# Frames from CAD to frames in Qgis

Tags: qgis, scale, scale-bar

I'm trying to use some frames from Autocad (DXF / DWG) as a frame in Qgis (*.qpt??) but I don't know how to do it or if it's possible. 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is currently no way to use Autocad files as QGIS print composer templates (I assume that's what you are trying to do).

Forget it and redo them by hand in print composer. It's just a few boxes and will be much faster than trying to find a way to convert these files.